# Event Listener in Google Orgchart, ignore selection event if a link in the node is clicked

Tags: jquery, google-visualization, listener

I have successfully implemented a version of the Google Orgchart that allows drill down and refresh of the chart on each node selection. However, I have some supplemental links embedded with each node after the first level, and I want to prevent the drill-down "refresh" of the chart from triggering if the user clicks on either of the links.

Is there a way to prevent the selection event from triggering in those instances?

Here is the code for the listener:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
var selection = chart.getSelection();
if (selection.length > 0 && data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0) != '10021917') {
mgrval = $('#managerid').text();
ldrval = $('#leaderid').text();
GetItemsLT(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0),mgrval, ldrval);
}
});
```

here is an example of in the node (has class of 'hrdata' universally for all of them):

```
<a href="https://browse.mycompany.com/detail.jsp?detail=less&amp;u=1061082" 
target="_blank"><img class="hrdata" src="https://kenvue.sharepoint.com/teams/nchc- 
compliance/officers/images/keds.png" height="50%" width="50%"></a>
```